# Делегирование JS

Tags: javascript, события

Изучаю чистый JavaScript. У меня есть три кнопки, которые обёрнуты в div. Необходимо сделать один обработчик для этих кнопок и разные действия по клику на каждую из них.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>

<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <button data-color="day">День</button>
    <button data-color="night">Ночь</button>
    <button data-color="red">Красный</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Все кнопки должны по клику делать alert с содержимым innerHTML.
Интересно исполнение при помощи нового стандарта ES6 и выше.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно повесить событие на родителя, а у события обращаться e.target, который будет содержать ссылку на элемент, на котором по факту произошел клик.

```js
let action = console.log
menu.addEventListener('click', e => e.target !== menu && action(e.target.dataset.color))
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <button data-color="day">День</button>
  <button data-color="night">Ночь</button>
  <button data-color="red">Красный</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Не могу понять, как это работает. Как получается передать menu без querySelector или getElement...? Обычно я бы задал переменную: let menu = document.getElementById('menu'). А тут почему-то и без этого работает

Comment: @ДаниилКедров если вы откроете в отладчике объект `window`, то сможете обнаружить там св-ва, имена которых это идентификаторы элементов со страницы, а значения - ссылки на них.

Comment: @ДаниилКедров `let menu = document.getElementById('menu')` никому не навредит

Comment: Понял, спасибо)

Comment: Но чем меньше кода, тем лучше же всегда, поэтому к этому и надо мне стремиться. У Вас получилась всего 1 строчка кода)

Comment: @ДаниилКедров в реальной жизни идентификаторы редко используются, а вот для сниппетов в самый раз

Comment: @ДаниилКедров ну не в строчках надо измерять, а в кол-ве действий, которые в этих строчках

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97099/discussion-between---and-stranger-in-the-q).

Answer (score 3):

```js
class Menu {
  constructor(node) {
    this.node = node;

    if (!this.node) return;

    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);

    this.node.addEventListener('click', this.onClick, false);
  }

  onClick(e) {
    const button = e.target.closest('button');

    if (!button) return;

    const color = this.getColor(button);

    console.log(color);
  }

  getColor(button) {
    return button.getAttribute('data-color');
  }
}

const root = document.querySelector('#menu');

new Menu(root);
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <button data-color="day">День</button>
  <button data-color="night">Ночь</button>
  <button data-color="red">Красный</button>
</div>
```

Comment: А что даёт проверка if (!this.node) return; ?

Comment: @ДаниилКедров, если `node` не будет передан, то скрипт не запуститься

Answer (score 1):

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('#menu');

menu.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    alert(e.target.innerHTML);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <button data-color="day">День</button>
  <button data-color="night">Ночь</button>
  <button data-color="red">Красный</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @РустамГимранов исправил

Comment: @РустамГимранов очевидно же, что из-за заголовка вопроса "Делегирование JS", если  повесить на прямую на каждую кнопку, то никакого делегирования не будет

Comment: @РустамГимранов я думаю потому что в заголовке мелькает делегирование

Comment: кстати строку `const menu = document.querySelector('#menu');` можно просто убрать =)

Comment: @РустамГимранов ну да, судя по телу вопроса обработчик может висеть на каждом элементе...

Answer (score 0):

```js
foo();
function foo() {
  let parent = document.getElementById('menu');
    if(!parent) return;
    
  parent.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    // Получаем элемент по которому произошел клик
    let target = event.target;
     
     // Проверяем наш ли это элемент
     if(target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
        let targetVal = target.innerHTML;
        alert(targetVal);
     }
    
  });
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>

<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <button data-color="day">День</button>
    <button data-color="night">Ночь</button>
    <button data-color="red">Красный</button>
  </div>
</body>
```